# How to disable access to certain credentials in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have configured a Github API token in Jenkins to be used in jobs to checkout the repos.
I also have the credentials binding plugin installed to inject other types of credentials into a pipeline using the `withCredentials` command.
But now each pipeline can read the GitHub API token using `withCredentials`. How can i restrict access to certain global credentials for all jobs?

Comment: Any solutions to this? We are facing the same issue, we do NOT want credentials from the parent folder to flow down into the child folders.

Answer (score 1):

We can create Credential object at folder level instead of Global. So that only the jobs which are in that folder can assess those credential objects. The jobs out of that folder can't access those credentials objects. This may help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I want developers to be able to use pre-configured credentials to configure jobs but they should not be able to fetch the API token with a pipeline script. So the level needs to be global to make them available for all jobs but I don't want them to be available in plain text.

Comment: You can create a folder for developers and create required credential objects at that folder level. So that developers can only access only those credential objects and they can't see the values also.

Comment: can you elaborate more? The problem I have is that no matter where I create those credentials they can use it to configure a GitHub source in a pipeline but they can also use the `withCredential` command in the Jenkinsfile and therefore can just misuse the credentials in a script.